# How to align HTML footer on document invisible area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I'm now working on a site that is a flash based responsive site.
Now my clients wants to add a html footer on this site and told me to do something that when the page is loaded the footer should be on the invisible area of the document but when anybody scroll down he/she will see the footer. And my client told me that this should be also responsive that it will work on any screen size.
Any body has any idea how to do it?

Comment: Tell them it's impossible.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible somehow... create an invisible footer div, and  on js event mouse scroll (scroll or scroll to the bottom?), make div visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this for cross-browser compatibility, but on firefox it works. It's only a proof of concept, I'm not sure you can modify your existing site without breaking everything up, but at least it's not impossible.
(For IE: you probably have to add a doctype declaration to force it into standards mode).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QkX32/

HTML:

```
<body>
     <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="mainPage"></div>
         <div id="footer"></div>
     </div>                
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}   

#mainPage{
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;    
}

#footer{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;  
    width: 100%;    
}

#wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scrollHeight` after the page is loaded(`.load`) positioning the div as `absolute` and using `.scrollHeight` as the value for the `top` parameter. This is done using jQuery, but you can achieve the same result using pure javascript.
E.g.

```
 function getheight(){
    var myheight = document.body.scrollHeight;
 }
 $(document).load(getheight(); #mydiv.css('top', myheight));
```

And in the css use a % value to obtain a liquid box:

```
#mydiv{
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if the (document - footer) is smaller than the window (that is at least part of the footer is visible),    and if so position the footer absolutely under the window

```
if (($(document).height()-$("footer").height())<$(window).height()){
$("footer").css({
"position":"absolute",
"top":$(window).height();
});
}
```